# C# "Method Name Expected"

Tags: c#

I'm making a very simple BMI Calculator that I had working already but had to change a rounding problem, now I'm running into "Method name expected" for the final output of userWeight and userHeight. Here is the code.

```
double userWeight;
double userHeight;
double userAnswer;

Console.WriteLine("Welcome to our program for calculating Body Mass Index");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your weight in pounds.");
userWeight = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your height in inches.");
userHeight = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

userAnswer = (userWeight / (userHeight * userHeight) * 703);

Console.WriteLine("The BMI of a person who weighs ") + userWeight ("pounds and is ") + userHeight ("inches tall has a BMI of ") + userAnswer;
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `Writeline()` method. Please change it this way:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The BMI of a person who weighs {userWeight} pounds and is {userHeight} inches tall has a BMI of {userAnswer}");
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of your Console.WriteLine is a bit off.  You wrote:

```
        Console.WriteLine("The BMI of a person who weighs ") + userWeight ("pounds and is ") + userHeight ("inches tall has a BMI of ") + userAnswer;
```

But what you want to do is this:

```
        Console.WriteLine("The BMI of a person who weighs " + userWeight + " pounds and is " + userHeight + " inches tall has a BMI of " + userAnswer);
```

There are other ways to format a string as the other folks have mentioned but this is adequate as well :).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: This prints double with two decimal digits.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The BMI of a person who weighs {0:0.00} pounds and is {1:0.00} inches tall has a BMI of {2:0.00}", userWeight, userHeight, userAnswer));
```

else simple way is:

```
Console.WriteLine("The BMI of a person who weighs " + userWeight + " pounds and is " + userHeight + " inches tall has a BMI of " + userAnswer);
```